# Better form of displaying system of equations in an enumerated list

Tags: equations, amsmath, systeme

The question is in the title of the question itself. I have the following code. What I need is to align each equation by the equal sign and start the first equation of each system at the same level as the **\item**. Any help is much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  letterpaper,
  lmargin=10 mm,
  rmargin=10 mm,
  tmargin=1 cm,
  bmargin=1 cm,
  footskip=9 pt,
  headheight=12 pt}  
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\linespread{1.2}

\renewenvironment{solution}{{\bf Solution:}}{\hfill}
\firstpagefooter
  {}
  {}
  {\textbf{[Turn over}}
\runningfooter
  {}
  {Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
  {\ifodd\value{page}
    \ifnum\value{page}<\numpages\textbf{[Turn over}\fi
  \fi}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}  


\item Find all existing solutions to the following linear systems, using the Gaussian elimination method with backward substitution.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item $4x-3y=10\\
8x-y=10$
\item $-3x+5y=-22\\3x+4y=4\\4x-8y=32$
\item $y+z=6\\3x-y+z=-7\\x+y-3z=-13$
\item $x+2y=0\\x+y=6\\3x-2y=8$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `cases`.

Comment: @Sigur, thank you. Could you please elaborate the use of \cases{ }. I have used that for stepwise functions but not for system of equations.

Comment: Do you want braces on the left or just the equations?

Comment: @Sigur, thank you. Without the braces would do. I use \systeme{ } with comes with braces to the left. But don't know how to remove the braces.

Comment: So, like this? `\item $\begin{aligned}[t]4x-3y=10\\8x-y=10\end{aligned}$`

Comment: Or `\item $\begin{aligned}[t]&4x-3y=10\\&8x-y=10\end{aligned}$` if you want to align to left.

Comment: @Sigur, thank you it worked. One quick question. How to align the coefficients when in one equation the coefficient of one variable is zero yet it aligns with the respective coefficients of the other equations.

Comment: Search for `aligned` here on TEX.SE and you will find a lot of examples. You have to align according to `&`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flalign*` from `mathtools`, or `aligned` in equations. From your code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  letterpaper,
  lmargin=10 mm,
  rmargin=10 mm,
  tmargin=1 cm,
  bmargin=1 cm,
  footskip=9 pt,
  headheight=12 pt}  
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\linespread{1.2}

\renewenvironment{solution}{{\bf Solution:}}{\hfill}
\firstpagefooter
  {}
  {}
  {\textbf{[Turn over}}
\runningfooter
  {}
  {Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
  {\ifodd\value{page}
    \ifnum\value{page}<\numpages\textbf{[Turn over}\fi
  \fi}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}  


\item Find all existing solutions to the following linear systems, using the Gaussian elimination method with backward substitution.
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item \begin{flalign*}
        4x-3y & = 10&\\
        8x-y & = 10&
    \end{flalign*}
\item \begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
       -3x+5y &=-22&\\
       3x+4y &=4& \\
       4x-8y&=32&
    \end{aligned}\right.
    \end{equation*}
\item $y+z=6\\3x-y+z=-7\\x+y-3z=-13$
\item $x+2y=0\\x+y=6\\3x-2y=8$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 0):

Hm, if I understood your question correctly, than you are after for following:

[image]

In this case instead of using `enumerate` in two columns environment it is better to use `tasks` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[margin=10mm,
            footskip=9 pt,
            headheight=12 pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*,
                      itemsep=\baselineskip,
                      label={\textbf{\thesection.\arabic*}}
                    }
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage{tasks} % <---
\settasks{label=(\alph*),
          label-format=\bfseries,
          label-offset=2em,
          label-align=right,
          before-skip =-0.5ex,
          after-item-skip=\medskipamount
          }

\begin{document}

\section{Section title}
    \begin{enumerate}
\item Find all existing solutions to the following linear systems, using the Gaussian elimination method with backward substitution.
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $\begin{aligned}[t]
        4x -3 y & = 10  \\
        8x -  y & = 10 
    \end{aligned}$
\task   \par\vspace{-1.3\baselineskip}% <--- this is special case due to use of braces
        $\left\{\begin{aligned}
       -3x + 5y & = -22 \\
        3x + 4y & =   4 \\
        4x - 8y & =  32
                \end{aligned}\right.$
\task $\begin{aligned}[t]
             y +  z & =  6   \\
        3x - y +  z & = -7   \\
         x + y - 3z & =-13
         \end{aligned}$
\task $\begin{aligned}[t]
        x + 2y & = 0 \\
        x +  y & = 6 \\
       3x - 2y & = 8
       \end{aligned}$
\end{tasks}   
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```